# Core dumped during 3D implementation of 'max area of islands' algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

I am trying to use [an algorithm](https://github.com/deepti-talesra/LeetCode/blob/master/Max_Area_of_Island.py) for the problem "[Max area of island](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-area-of-island/)" in a 3D problem, so it would be more like max volume of island. I was using total volumes of 200x200x200 voxels as input, but I am having trouble because it does not work when there are very big 'islands' in the volume I input ('core dumped' in the Ubunut terminal). Here is the code with the modifications I did to apply it to my 3D problem:

```
class Solution3D:

    def dfs3D(self, grid, r, c, l):
        grid[r][c][l] = 0
        num = 1
        lst = [(r-1, c, l), (r+1, c, l), (r, c-1, l), (r, c+1, l), (r, c, l-1), (r, c, l+1)]
        for row, col, leh in lst:
            if row >= 0 and col >= 0 and leh >= 0\
            and row < len(grid) and col < len(grid[0]) and leh < len(grid[0][0])\
            and grid[row][col][leh] == 1:
                num += self.dfs3D(grid, row, col, leh)
        return num


    def maxAreaOfIsland3D(self, grid):
        area_islands = 0
        for r in range(len(grid)):
            for c in range(len(grid[0])):
                for l in range(len(grid[0][0])):
                    if grid[r][c][l] == 1:
                        area_islands = max(area_islands, self.dfs3D(grid, r, c, l))
        return area_islands
```

Is this implementation too inefficient? How could I make it less memory hungry so that I can use it with big islands?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Very interesting problem! I must go to sleep now, but share what idea I have. 1) Find islands in 2D slices. 2) Find which 2D islands are connected to each other in neighbouring slices. Maybe use some graph package, giving each node the size of 2D island). 3) Find graph with highest nodes values

Comment: You really just get "core dumped"?  Where?  I'm wondering if the actual problem is that you're using an array of arrays of arrays, and should instead be using numpy, which could hold the grid more compactly.  Python doesn't typically just die without telling you where.

Comment: I think the problem is with recursion depth and the stack limit. Try to use BFS instead of DFS or increase the stack limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got something. Takes around one minute and 6GB of RAM

1. First I find edges using `sklearn.image.grid_to_graph`, this is quite fast
2. Next I build `networkx` graph - this is bottleneck for both computation time and RAM usage
3. Finally, I find all connected subgraphs in this graph and retu

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import sklearn.feature_extraction.image

grid_size = 4   # manual check -> for seed 0: 38 nodes, largest subgraph has 37 connected nodes, correct
grid_size = 200


random_grid = np.random.RandomState(seed=0).randint(0, 2, size=(grid_size, grid_size, grid_size))
G = nx.Graph()
print('finding edges...')
graph = sklearn.feature_extraction.image.grid_to_graph(grid_size, grid_size, grid_size, mask=random_grid)
print('buidling graph...')
G.add_edges_from(np.vstack([graph.col, graph.row]).T)
print('finding subgraphs...')
subgraphs = nx.connected_components(G)
sorted_subgraphs = sorted(subgraphs, key=len, reverse=True)
G0 = G.subgraph(sorted_subgraphs[0])
print('Largest subgraph size: ', len(G0))
```

```
Largest subgraph size:  3909288
```